# Bonding / Link aggregation / NIC teaming for faster transfer

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, download-speed, network-bonding

I am working on a home server and want to utilize more than one 1Gb connection to my servers, to make for instance 4Gb connection with 4 cables.

My question is how to achieve this with Ubuntu server 18.04.3 LTS and [Longshine LCS-GS9324](http://manual.longshine.de/3_Network_Driver/1000MBIT_Network/LCS-GS9324/gs9324-eng.pdf). That is a smart switch and does not support IEEE 802.3ad, which would allow me to run my bond in mode 4.

I have already played a bit with the configs, but I did not manage to get any higher speeds. And I do not need any backup lines, just more speed.

All help and links that could solve this are highly appreciated.

Comment: @K7AAY question edited.